# Google Cloud Storage GoLang : Error Handling

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I'm using the Golang Client Library for Google Cloud Storage to fetch and retrieve data from Google Bucket.

But I cannot find a way to do some error handling. The SDK returns some strings and there is no documentation around that. It would have been good if they sent error codes.

This page https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/googlecloudstorageclient/errors talks about only 2 errors.

Perhaps, I'm missing something. Is it possible to get error codes?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [documentation for Google Cloud Storage Client package](https://godoc.org/cloud.google.com/go/storage#hdr-Errors)

> Errors returned by this client are often of the type
> `googleapi.Error`.
> These errors can be introspected for more information by type
> asserting to the richer `googleapi.Error` type. For example:
>
> ```
> if e, ok := err.(*googleapi.Error); ok {
>     if e.Code == 409 { ... }
> }
> ```

Comment: This works for me, but could someone explain `err.(*googleapi.Error)`?  I'm a new golanger.

Comment: That is a type assertion:  https://go.dev/ref/spec#Type_assertions

Comment: We are asserting that the error is of type *googleapi.Error. If it is not of that type, or at least implements that interface if that is an interface. If it is of that type (or implements the interface), e will then be that value of that type and ok will be true. If err is not of type *googleapi.Error (or doesn’t implement that interface) then ok will be false.

Comment: So we are making an assignment to e only in the case where err is of the type we are looking for. This allows us to guard actions specific to that error type inside the scope of that block.